# how to count number of a specific function be called at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

A program is divided into N functions.

Like the following code snippets: after calling each function, I wanna show the progress `count/N`

how to count N at compile time ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double progress()
{
    int const total = 4; // how to get 4?
    static int counter = 0;
    return static_cast<double>(counter++) / static_cast<double>(total);
}

int main()
{
    cout << progress() << endl; // 0.25
    cout << progress() << endl; // 0.5
    cout << progress() << endl; // 0.75
    cout << progress() << endl; // 1.0
    return 0;
}
```

I tried constexpr function, but cannot increment a variable.

Comment: Instead of using functions with static variables, this would be better done by writing a class which stores `counter` and `total` as members and with an overloaded `operator()`. This can also be achieved with a lambda.

Comment: Imagine this: `string s; getline(cin, s); for (char c : s) cout << progress() << endl;` -- now what? How many calls are made? There's only one in a loop, and the number of calls is determined by user input.

Comment: How do you expect the compiler while compiling the implementation of `progress()` to know how many times the function is called at run time ? (keep in mind there could be other translation units calling it, and/or calls might be conditional).

Comment: Oh, are you saying that you want to determine the number of times that the function _will_ be called? That is obviously impossible. It can depend on the input from outside the program and even if it didn't, figuring that out would be equivalent to solving the halting problem, which is known to not be computable.

Comment: This seems like XY Problem, too. Clearly there's a need to make it easier to add "tasks" this program must perform, and update progress without having to modify the value. That could be achieved by registering each task as a lambda or whatever and storing in a container. Then, the container size becomes the count and the loop that processes the tasks can show progress accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the following code:

```
int main() {
    cout << "N = ";
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) cout << 'progress()' << endl;
}
```

There is absolutely no way, the compiler can know how many times the function will be executed. So you need to determine the number using the logic of your data.

If you want to know how many times you call `progress` without loops, recursions, conditions etc., the only way I can think of is using external tool on the source file. E.g.

```bash
cat source.cpp | grep -o progress() | wc -l
```

Just remember to subtract 1 from the result, which accounts for the function definition.

Comment: Or subtract `2` if you separate the declaration and definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, but you could fake it by making the printing happen after `N` (function call count) is known.

```cpp
static struct counter_impl {
  int n = 0;
  constexpr void operator ()() noexcept { ++n; }
  
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, counter_impl const& self) {
    os << std::fixed;
    std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<double>(os, "\n"), self.n,
      [i = 1, N = static_cast<double>(self.n)] () mutable { return i++ / N; });
    return os << std::defaultfloat;
  }
} counter;

int main() {
  counter();
  std::cout << counter; // 1.00
}
```

[Live example on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:27,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:27,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:27,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:27),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciomanip%3E%0A%0Astatic+struct+counter_impl+%7B%0A++int+n+%3D+0%3B%0A++constexpr+void+operator+()()+noexcept+%7B+%2B%2Bn%3B+%7D%0A++%0A++friend+std::ostream%26+operator%3C%3C(std::ostream%26+os,+counter_impl+const%26+self)+%7B%0A++++os+%3C%3C+std::fixed%3B%0A++++std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator%3Cdouble%3E(os,+%22%5Cn%22),+self.n,%0A++++++%5Bi+%3D+1,+N+%3D+static_cast%3Cdouble%3E(self.n)%5D+()+mutable+%7B+return+i%2B%2B+/+N%3B+%7D)%3B%0A++++return+os+%3C%3C+std::defaultfloat%3B%0A++%7D%0A%7D+counter%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++counter()%3B%0A++counter()%3B%0A++counter()%3B%0A++counter()%3B%0A++counter()%3B%0A++counter()%3B%0A++std::cout+%3C%3C+counter%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1301,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Weverything+-Wno-padded+-Wno-c%2B%2B98-compat+-Wno-c%2B%2B20-compat-pedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+13.0.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you cannot.

This is not something that can be determined at compile time.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem